# How to change range of values to actual values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have data in pandas dataframe where the column values look like 732-738 i want to expand these range of values into separate rows and in doing so also expand the next column values as well can anyone suggest me a way to do it?

```
 Destination ZIP    Zone    
  732-738             8 
   005                7
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```py
def func(custom_range):
    start, end = tuple(map(int, custom_range.split("-")))
    return list(range(start, end+1))

col = ['Destination_ZIP','Zone']
data = [['732-738','8'], ['005','7']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)
mask = df["Destination_ZIP"].str.contains('-')
df.loc[mask, "Destination_ZIP"] = df.loc[mask, "Destination_ZIP"].apply(func)
df = df.explode("Destination_ZIP")
print(df)
```

outputs:

```
  Destination_ZIP Zone
0             732    8
0             733    8
0             734    8
0             735    8
0             736    8
0             737    8
0             738    8
1             005    7
```

Comment: nice solution! you forgot to add the "738" number at your output ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
df['Destination']=df['Destination'].apply(lambda x:  range([int(i) for i in x.split('-')][0],[int(i) for i in x.split('-')][1]+1) if "-" in x else x)

df.explode('Destination')


  Destination_ZIP Zone
0             732    8
0             733    8
0             734    8
0             735    8
0             736    8
0             737    8
0             738    8
1             005    7
```